# Octet to string conversion

Tags: java, c++

How to convert t-octet into string? I am doing some service on C++, now stuck here I have to write a function that can convert t-octet to string. for more clarification I am getting call reference number from IDP(Initial detection point) in form of t-octet which I have to save in database in form of simple String.

Plz give some Idea.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why did you tag this `Java`? What is a `t-octet`?

Comment: this function can be written in any lang either C++ or Java and t-octet is a type of String

Comment: Java and C++ don't have the same type of string objects. And "a type of string" doesn't say much.

Comment: If you know exactly what a t-octet is, try telling us. If you don't, then finding out will help you in working out how to convert it to whatever form it is you want it in.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I *assume* a T-Octed is a string of octets, meaning an 8 bit integer in this sense because it is a telephone number. I'm not really into java, but I am sure you can use string.Format: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1195/ to convert an integer to string format. Just for loop over your string of octets and convert each octet into a string. You should then concatenate the strings together to get a string version of the telephone number. Just cast each to an int if they don't fit.
In C++ what I often do is just take char mah_char = '0' + mah_int;
Which of course only works for single digit numbers.
Hope that helps.